# New Question notifications are not getting pushed in Newest tab

Tags: support, live-refresh

Until this new build of stackoverflow, which happened about couple of week ago.

I use to get new questions automatically getting pushed to web-page with () appended to the title of browser tab.

This is not happening recently, is this feature deprecated in recent build ?

Or is it something to do with my network firewall ? any clues how can i enable it?

Comment: this feature only work in active tab

Comment: it use to work in `newest` tab

Comment: [I can see the number of new questions in the title of the newest tab.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IALJt.png)

Comment: seems like its related to my network, any one has a clue whether push alone can be blocked to a url ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally im able to findout the reason, My network firewall is blocking `WebSocket`s which is essential for the SO / SE for communicating Notifications.

Able to findout the reason : Its Firefox BlockSite's blocklist to which url `sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/` automatically got added.

Comment: You mean [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/blocksiteplus/)?

Comment: No, [This one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/blocksite/)